# How to export named data.frame list to files with its name in purrr

Tags: r, list, purrr

For a list with named data.frames, is it possible to write to different files with name in purrr workflow? I do this with `for`.

```
dfs <-list(cars_head = head(cars),
           cars_tail = tail(cars))

for (name in names(dfs)){ write.csv(dfs[[name]], paste0(name, ".csv")) }
```

I want to do with purrr workflow, but don't know how to get the data.frame name(????).

```
list(cars_head = head(cars),
     cars_tail = tail(cars)) %>%
map(.x = ., .f = write.csv( .x, paste0(????, ".csv"))
```

Comment: list(cars_head = head(cars),
     cars_tail = tail(cars)) %>%
imap(.x = ., .f = write.csv( .x, paste0(.y, ".csv"))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `imap` in `purrr` which allows you to access data as well as list name.

```
purrr::imap(dfs, ~write.csv(.x, paste0(.y, '.csv'), row.names = FALSE))
```

`purrr` also has `iwalk` function which can be used in the same way :

```
purrr::iwalk(dfs, ~write.csv(.x, paste0(.y, '.csv'), row.names = FALSE))
```