# save list elements into separated dfs in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, save

I have a list containing 180.000 elements each represents data about an investor and a specific traded asset.
I want to save all the elements of the list into single dataframes called df into a specific folder `"dev/test-data/investors-singleass/"` , so that I can later on apply a specific function on all the dfs of the folder

The list of my data has a structure similar to this

```
list(`4Z627.004125` = structure(list(investor = c("4Z627", "4Z627", 
"4Z627"), asset = c("004125", "004125", "004125"), datetime = c("2015-05-12", 
"2015-05-28", "2016-08-19"), Avgprice = c(169.4, 168, 162), operation = c(2000, 
1000, -3000), portfolio = c(2000, 3000, 0), last_port = c(0, 
2000, 3000), marketprice = c(169.4, 166.5, 161.75), portprice = c(169.4, 
168.933333333333, 0), G = c(0, 0, 1), gainminus = c(2, 0, 0), 
    numasset = c(5, 8, 13)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Basically each elements of the list is an "investor" ID and an "asset" code for which i then have multiple other columns to work with

Comment: Please be precise in what your data format is and provide some example data of the list e.g. using `dput(head(my_big_list))`

Comment: now it should be better

Comment: So you want your folder to look like "dev/test-data/investors-singleass/4Z627.004125.csv"?

Comment: all the data must become an .RData but later on I want R to apply the same function on all the new created DFs so it is important that all the single DFs are called "df" when loaded into the environment

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you try to do, but this would save the list as a dataframe in an RData Object:
`purrr::iwalk(yourlist, ~saveRDS(.x, paste0("dev/test-data/investors-singleass/","df.RData")))`

Comment: I think i'm not clear in what I'm looking for. To recall your previous answer I want my folder to look like "dev/test-data/investors-singleass/4Z627.004125.RData" and this must hold for all the different 180K elements of the list, so I need to get 180k differend RData in the folder

Comment: in the past i worked with `setwd("C:/Users/Lorenzo/Desktop/Bologna_R/dev/test-data/investors-rdata-assetbased")
library(purrr)
map(.x = names(dfs), .f = function(x){
  assign(x, dfs[[x]])
  save(list = x, file = paste0(x, ".RData"))
}
)` where dfs is the name of the list, but the problem here is that assign created different dfs which I'm not able to load in the environment since they are RData files with different names. I'm not able to apply the same function on all of them

Comment: Do you really need to export your data as RData? It sounds to me that you want to apply the same function on all lists, i.e. on each investor-asset combination. You can do this with `purrr::map` or `lapply`. I do not get why you need to got the long way to export the data and import it again to apply your function.

Comment: I think i'll end up with a memory problem if I just apply the function to all the entire elements of the list in a single shot. I want to save the single RData such that i would then be able to just apply the function recalling smaller arguments

Comment: You could also create sublists, e.g. for the first 30000 lists: `sublist <- df[1:30000]`, and then you apply your function on each sublists and in the end bind the results together `bind_rows()` - maybe that could solve your memory ploblem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this based on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419733/how-to-export-named-data-frame-list-to-files-with-its-name-in-purrr)

```
df1 <- list(`4Z627.004125` = structure(list(investor = c("4Z627", "4Z627", 
                                                  "4Z627"), asset = c("004125", "004125", "004125"), 
                                     datetime = c("2015-05-12",   "2015-05-28", "2016-08-19"), 
                                     Avgprice = c(169.4, 168, 162), 
                                     operation = c(2000, 1000, -3000), portfolio = c(2000, 3000, 0),
                                     last_port = c(0,2000, 3000), marketprice = c(169.4, 166.5, 161.75), 
                                     portprice = c(169.4, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        168.933333333333, 0), G = c(0, 0, 1), gainminus = c(2, 0, 0), 
                                     numasset = c(5, 8, 13)), row.names = c(NA, -3L),
                                     class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")),
            `4Z628.004128` = structure(list(investor = c("4Z627", "4Z627", 
                                                         "4Z627"), asset = c("004125", "004125", "004125"), 
                                            datetime = c("2015-05-12",   "2015-05-28", "2016-08-19"), 
                                            Avgprice = c(169.4, 168, 162), 
                                            operation = c(2000, 1000, -3000), portfolio = c(2000, 3000, 0),
                                            last_port = c(0,2000, 3000), marketprice = c(169.4, 166.5, 161.75), 
                                            portprice = c(169.4, 
                                                          168.933333333333, 0), G = c(0, 0, 1), gainminus = c(2, 0, 0), 
                                            numasset = c(5, 8, 13)), row.names = c(NA, -3L),
                                       class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
library(purrr)
iwalk(df1, ~saveRDS(.x, paste0("dev/test-data/investors-singleass/", .y, '.RData')))
```

You can get the data back into R with

```
library(dplyr)

df <- list.files(path = "dev/test-data/investors-singleass/", pattern = ".RData") %>% 
  map_dfr(readRDS)
```

Comment: it gives me an error with the iwalk() function saying it cannot open the connection plus In gzfile(file, mode) :
  cannot open compressed file 'dev/test-data/investors-singleass/1.RData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: sounds like a path issue, try `paste0(getwd(),"/dev/test-data/investors-singleass/", .y, '.RData')`

Comment: now it works but i'm not able to load the files with your second command, it tells me Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file '412Z8.006420.RData', probable reason 'No such file or directory'

Comment: Same issue, the path is not correct, try again with `path = paste0(getwd(),"/dev/test-data/investors-singleass/")`